# Keep project history when transforming project in module in SONARQUBE

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube

I recently attempted to change a sonar project into another project module.
I found out in [SONAR-4245](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4245) that the existing project has to be delete in order to have it in a module.

However, I would like to keep the project history.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible, and we don't plan to make it possible for the moment.